# Unable to start process dotnet.exe

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, .net-core

I am attempting to setup a new work space and transfer all of my projects from my old computer to the new one.  However, I am getting this error when I try to run IIS Express:

> Unable to start process C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe. The web
>   server request failed with status code 500.

I am working in Visual Studio 2015, update 3 and I am using .NET Core RC2.  Does anyone have any idea how to fix this and get my old projects running on this new machine?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to run an executable under IIS express. I think that your project file is a bit messed up.

Comment: http://dot.net upgrade from RC2 to RTM.

Comment: I have had this problem, when trying to rename my namespace - just open up `launchsettings.json` file and change the port number to something else, then , do a `dotnet build` or build from VS and try hitting the launch with IIS Express

Comment: I'm able to solve this issue Changing `modules="AspNetCoreModule"` from `modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" ` in `web.config`. My project environment is dotnet core 2.1 and vs2017. The docs says for dotnet core v2.1 it needs to be `modules="AspNetCoreModule" ` and for dotnet core 2.2 or higher it needs be  `modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" `. Full line here `<handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>`

Comment: My problem was also with module="AspNetCoreModuleV2". In my case another developer had unknowingly pushed web.config because his newer version of VS had conveniently changed it for him. Rather than me changing it back, I chose to update my VS to version 15.9.13 which fixed the issue.

Comment: If you run your app in x86 (32bit) - make sure you have DotNetCore 32 bit installed. https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/ Likewise for 64 bit.

Answer (score 111):

I was having the same problem. I look for dotnet.exe in that directory and it exists but debugger cannot execute it, so i Restart Visual Studio 2015 as administrator and it works!

Comment: It just amazes me how many problems can be solved by simply restarting VS.

Comment: @JeanLourenço it amazes me how often we have to do so, I love Visual Studio but it seems "with great power comes great responsibility", hopefully VS15 will assist in this by not requiring the full goliath IDE.

Comment: not sure how its possible. closed and opened the VS. it started working.. any explanation about how this is happening?

Comment: Running as admin might cause a lot of other problems in later phases (files are stored in the wrong places, the final app NOT running as admin etc ... )

Comment: Why its happens?

Comment: This just happened in Sep 2018. Microsoft this isn't good enough - stop adding features, fix the bugs first!

Comment: Nice one,. Thanks!

Comment: This just happened in Apr 2019, VS 2017. Restarting VS fixed the problem. For what might caused the issue, I use a scheduled task to sync my project folder between multiple machines. The last sync happened while the project was kept open in VS on another computer. It could be the sync picked up a "working" file (as Alban's answer suggested) and caused the problem on a different machine. If this is the case, VS is really not the one to blame.

Answer (score 36):

Just close VS delete the project.lock.json file,  open VS the file will be restored and you shouldn't have problems anymore.

Comment: Thank you. This fixed it for me as well. It was caused by moving the solution to a different location on disk. The .NET Core development experience continues to brighten my day

Answer (score 22):

The issue in my case was

1- I upgrade (ported) my project (console/website) from `.net 4.5 framework` to `donetcoreapp 2.0`

2- .NET Framework 4.5 project had Web.Config

3- dotnetcore 2.0 does not have concept of maintaining web.config.

4- So whenever I ran the project I got the same error

**solution:**

Just deleted `'Web.Config'` and it started working for me.

Comment: I only deleted the Web.Config file from my .Web project and after everything works good. Im using VS 2017. Thanks for the solution :)

Comment: Wao! Deleting the `web.config` just worked like a charm - Thanks.

Comment: So dumb.  If only we got an error like ".NET Core doesn't use web.configs.  Delete it!".   >.<  Thank you for this solution

Answer (score 14):

in my case. i choose "ProjectName" instead of "IIS Express" while running/debugging. and it works/open with a console output window and selected browser, keep console output window open while debugging. Hope this will work.

Answer (score 13):

Visual Studio 2017 -> The fix for me was to choose the Project Name instead of IISExpress when debugging/running.

Answer (score 8):

1. Close VS 2015 (it seems that the issue is resolved in VS 2017).
2. Remove all files in \bin and \obj. Remove project.lock.json.
3. Run VS.
4. Rebuild.

If the above solution doesnt work in VS2017 .Net Core, Run as VS2017 as ADMIN.
If no ADMIN access to your machine, you can change the 'launchSettings.json' to work on port 8080 like below and after that follow above 4 steps.

"applicationUrl": "http://localhost:8080/",

Comment: Regarding "it seems that the issue is resolved in VS 2017"<- Nope. Not yet at least for VS 2017 15.5.2. That's how I ended up finding this question.

Answer (score 5):

This is what worked for me:

> I've had the same issue, and it turned out that I simply didn't have the right version of the runtime (1.1.0); instead I was trying to use 1.1.0 assemblies with 1.0.1 runtime.
>
> The resolution is simple - download and install SDK from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core), but pick the right version! It turned out that if you want version 1.1.0 you should select "Current" option (button).
>
> Basically the problem is caused by stupid interface at the referenced page - if you don't pay attention you'll download v1.0.1 since it is "LTS" version, and "LTS" option is default there. What to say... Yet another disappointment from .NET team in this crazy-versioning, crazy-moniker, crazy-platform times...

The quotes are from peske: https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1719

Comment: Something I did since I just got to a new company and tried attaching to process and it freaked. If you type `dotnet --version into the package manager console and check it against other people that don't have the issue that could point to a problem with the sdk version.

Answer (score 4):

I have this issue right after updating Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 pro, so far I found 3 potential solutions :

- Restart Visual Studio works, sometimes,
- Delete %USERPROFILE%.nuget may solve the issue,
- Uninstall, then reinstall dotnet SDK,

Comment: Delete %USERPROFILE%\.nuget may solve the issue,

Answer (score 4):

this is an answer to an issue slightly different to what OP has posted. If the error message has just "dotnet.exe", not the full path of dotnet.exe("C:\ProgramFiles\DotNet\dotnet.exe"), then check if the dotnet.exe is in System.Environment path, if not add it and run VS as an admin

Answer (score 4):

In your startup project be sure that you have selected the option Enable Anonymous Authentication
[image]

Comment: I had unauthorized issue; this fixed it

Answer (score 4):

The solution in my case was deleted web.config from the root of the project. I was working on an ASPnetcore project and after a week the error started. I am unsure how that web.config file got added but once I delete that their error got resolved.

Answer (score 3):

Solution for me was to close visual studio 2017, and reopen the solution. :)

Answer (score 3):

I was able to fix the error by **removing**  $(solutionDir).vs\config\**applicationhost.config**.  After restart VS 2017 recreated the file.
 The file became invalid after I moved the solution from one location to another.

Thanks to  https://elanderson.net/2016/09/unable-to-start-process-dotnet-exe/ for the idea.

Answer (score 3):

It is caused by a wrong Path in **applicationhost.config** file, this file you can find inside your project folder. Go to your project folder. There you will find a **.vs**  named folder, if you can not find it then in folder open You have to Uncheck Hidden folder. Once you have found it navigate to **config**  folder there you find **applicationhost.config**. Open this file in notepad and provide your project location like that:-

`<virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="c:\users\*****\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\<ProjectFolderName>\<Projectname>" />`

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

Solution for me (without administrator rights) was to:

- Close all instances of visual studio 2017
- Open project
- Clean
- Rebuild
- Run

Answer (score 1):

VS2017 and solution has .NET Core 1.1 web applications.

This did not help: Deleting .VS folder, removing all bin directories, restarting VS.

This helped: **Installed latest SDK** (.NET Core SDK 1.0.4) this issue got resolved.

I got this issue all of a sudden after a machine reboot followed by installing PHP for IIS, IIS URL Rewrite. But just try reinstalling the SDK – it might work fine with that itself, instead of going for the latest SDK.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution by reinstalling  **.NET CORE SDK**

Answer (score 1):

`iisreset` in cmd as Administrator did the work for me.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I accidentally install dotnet for x86 platform when my VS 2017 have x64. I reinstall dotnet for platform x64 and it works fine now.

Comment: Ok. I have Windows 10 with x64 arch and VS2017 Professional for x64 arch. Our project was updated to .NET Core v2.1.401. I got error from question. I decide update .NET Core SDK to v2.1.401 but accidentally download and install .NET Core SDK for x86 arch. I got error from question. And after some time I remarked that I have installer for x86 arch and then download and install .NET Core SDK for x64 arch. My project build and run fine like before update.

Answer (score 1):

If using `IIS` instead of `IIS Express`, just restart the service or:

1. open IIS
2. open your project folder from `Sites` tree view
3. select `site`
4. in `Manage Website`click on `Restart` button

Answer (score 1):

For whom is having problem with Visual Studio 2019 because was using the previous version of Visual Studio, jus delete the .vs folder that is in the root of the project and rerun the application, the problem must be resolved. That worked for me.

Comment: This should be the first thing you do.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. I have removed the .vs folder from the project folder. It solved my issue.
2. The .vs folder will be created when the project runs

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have a few projects in one solution and none of them has been set up as startup project.

So, just right-click on project (not solution!) as choose *Set as StartUp Project*.

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was a setting in web.config and timeout was not defined properly, TFS placeholder was there instead of actual value `requestTimeout="00:06:00"`

Here is what it looks like. Hope it will be helpfull

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="aspNetCore"/>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" requestTimeout="00:06:00" />
    <httpRedirect enabled="false" />
  </system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this and it turns out I was in Release build.  Changed to Debug build and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I just change `modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2"`  to  `modules="AspNetCoreModule"` and working fine. The final web.config looks like as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" startupTimeLimit="3600" requestTimeout="23:00:00">
      <environmentVariables />
    </aspNetCore>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to do a repair installation of .net core 2.2 sdk to fix this issue. Using VS 2017.

Answer (score 0):

My problem resolved by:

Goto: .vs\config\applicationhost.config file
and set overrideModeDefault to Allow instead of Deny

```
<section name="windowsAuthentication" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like you don't have `<appSettings>` tag in your web.config. If you add that you will be able to resolve this problem.

For Example :

```
<appSettings>
<add key="TestKey" value="TestValue"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the error returned was `503`, not `500`. It turned out that the application pool for the web site was using an account that had the password changed. Updating the password for the application pool identity resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found myself running into a similar issue following an update to **Docker**. The update must have restored configuration settings to default as the error message stated: `Access is denied.`

If anyone runs into that dilemma, try doing a clean uninstall and re-install of Docker following install recommendations for your OS (ex: Windows with WSL 2 backend) and then remove the .vs folder of your project and try restarting Visual Studio and **run with administrator**.

After all this, if you're still running into the error, make sure you have the right SDK installed!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had a DLL that was using .Net 6,
However the application which was referring it was .Net 5.
 Updating the application to .Net 6 solved my issue, if you cant upgrade your application, downgrading the DLL to .Net 5 would be the next best thing to do if possible.