# Unable to start program "C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe"

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I've installed .NET Core 1.0.1 to use with VS 2015 Update 3 and I'm running as Administrator (on Windows 8.1 x64).

If I create *any* .NET Core project, be it console or web and attempt to *run* it Visual Studio then comes up with an error:

[image]

However I'm unable to ascertain why. VS builds it fine and I can run it from the CLI. I can also run Core fine through VSCode.

I've tried:

- Deleting `project.lock.json`
- Deleting the `.vs` folder
- Repairing the .NET Core install
- Repairing the VS 2015 install
- Uninstalling and reinstalling .NET Core/SDK/Tooling & VS
- Rebooting

And it still refuses to work!

I've raised this on the Core Tooling GitHub as well as can be seen [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/807) but as yet we're all a little stumped.

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38488503/unable-to-start-process-dotnet-exe

Comment: Also related: https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/850

Comment: It isn't clear what is giving the answer. Could you please add a screenshot of the error to your answer.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin Yes I've seen those and non of their *solutions* work.

Comment: Two possible thoughts - is it a bitness issue? (A 32 bit VS launching a 64 bit dotnet)? If not that, can you trying just setting the permissions on the executable wide open, at least long enough to rule that out.

Comment: Have you checked if the windows event log has some more info about the issue?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42269963/cant-debug-anymore-net-core-in-visual-studio-2015-unable-to-start-dotnet-exe

Answer (score 1):

There are some people who have problems with Internet Explorer and Visual Studio.
Attempt to install Internet Explorer 9, or set a different default browser.

Other approaches:

1. Was the data path checked?
2. Perhaps there are wrong configured environment variables?
3. Are you sure that the configuration was reset by the installation?
4. Perhaps the path for the temporary data has been changed?

Comment: This is Windows 8.1 so it's IE10 but Chrome is the default, but this isn't anything to do with the browser per say. We've been discussing the env-vars on Github and I had DNX in there but that's removed now. The configuration et al was reset and temp hasn't changed.

Answer (score 1):

Try re-installing needed redistributables, as they are needed for executing .Net Core on Windows, as it is stated here :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/windows-prerequisites
"NET Core requires the VC++ Redistributable when running on Windows"

If it don't work, add a try/catch at the highest level of your application and log all System.Exceptions that may occur. It may give you more informations about this error.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs if you change the name of the project. To work around this error You will have to delete all files under \object and \bin folders. After that rebuild application.

Answer (score -1):

Restart the visual studio in administrator mode. This solved my problem.