# Can't debug anymore NET Core in Visual Studio 2015: Unable to start dotnet.exe

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, anaconda, .net-core

I am experiencing a problem like the one exposed in this SO question:

[Unable to start program "C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39938453/unable-to-start-program-c-program-files-dotnet-dotnet-exe)

I am asking this question not to create a duplicate but to provide more info and because the problem started only after the day I installed Python from its main website, Python Tools from Microsoft and Anaconda from Continuum. I'd bet the Anaconda is the guilty.

When I create any .NET Core project, be it console or web, and I attempt to debug it in Visual Studio 2015 I get this error:

[image]

I did the Python installations both on a Windows 7 SP1 pc and on a Windows 10 pc. Until then I  was able to create, compile and debug a Net Core project in Visual Studio 2015 without any problem. When I started VS 2015 a couple of days after the Python installations, both my computers had the problem.

It's not a problem of Net Core, it is a Visual Studio 2015 problem. I am sure because if I build and run from CLI or if I debug using Visual Studio Code everything works as expected, the problem only affects Visual Studio 2015 Community.

Following several posts on the subject I have tried different proposed solutions, without success:

- Rebooted infinite times both Windows 7 and Windows 10.
- Reset Visual Studio Settings.
- Deleted project.json and lock file I deleted the .vs folder.
- Repaired .Net Core.
- Repaired VS 2015.
- Uninstalled Python, Python tools, Anaconda.
- Uninstalled / reinstalled Visual Studio 2015 and Net Core Tools for
  VS several times.
- Uninstalled and reinstalled the VC++ redistributable, x86 and x64.
- Tried to run VS in normal mode and as administrator.
- Forced to run dotnet.exe as administrator.
- Created new HelloWorld projects from scratch.
- Opened projects created with Visual Studio Code that can be debugged
  without any error in Visual Studio Code.
- Redone the login.
- Used VS 2015 without login.
- Selected in Debug Options: Use Managed Compatibily Mode
- Selected in Debug Options: Use Native Compatibility Mode
- Selected in Debug Options both the Options

The problem appears when I start the debug with the "play button" or when I select Debug-> Start Debugging (F5). The code compiles without errors then the message box appears when the app, even a simple "Hello World", should start.

- Options are set to Debug/Any Cpu.
- The file dotnet.exe is in its folder as expected.
- If I use Process Monitor I can see the process dotnet.exe is created
  with success as child of devenv.exe and then immediately exited, with
  0.0000 user time and kernel time.

**If I select Debug -> Start Without Debugging (CTRL+F5) the code runs without problems.**

If I select Debug -> Attach To Process -> dotnet.exe [type Managed (Core CLR), x64], default transport I get the error: "Unable to attachto the process. No more data is available"

Any hint to solve this without formatting the disk and reinstalling from scratch Windows?

**Edit**:

This is the project.json for a new created solution, a standard "Hello World":

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "type": "platform",
      "version": "1.0.1"
    }
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
}
```

The "Path" value in Environment Variables, for "all users" is:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32;
%SystemRoot%;
%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;
%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;
C:\blp\API;C:\blp\API\dde;
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\;
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;
C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;
C:\Program Files\dotnet\;
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
```

For my user only is:

```
C:\blp\DAPI;
C:\blp\DAPI\DDE;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\bin
```

Comment: check your project.json all package target same dotnet core versions.

Comment: Can you check your %PATH% variable? (Ctrl+Pause, Advanced System settings, Advanced tab, Environment variables and PATH for both user and system variables. Some programs, especially opensource commandline stuff have prohibitively long Pathes (and often multiple pathes) added there. The limit lies somewhere between 2047 and 4095 characters depending on your version of the OS

Comment: I added it as Edit in the question

Comment: did you get error on  standard "Hello World" program as well ?

Comment: yes. Same error even for a simple System.Console.WriteLine("Hello World");

Comment: Try using the commandline: `dotnet.exe --version` (what does it say?) and `dotnet build path/to/project` `dotnet start`, what errors are you getting? Otherwise i suggest installing a newer version of the [dotnet SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core)

Comment: On the Win10 pc it says 1.0.0-preview2-003131. On the windows 7 pc I installed also the 1.1 Net Core but it didn't fixed it. Today I also installed VS 2017 RC and everything runs fine in it as it does in VS Code, I only had to migrate from project.json to the new format. In VS 2015 I still have the problem.