# Unable to run asp.net core project in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, runtime-error, visual-studio-2017

Please help with the next error in VS 2017

[image]

I am unable to run an ASP.NET Core project due to this error.

The question is about VS 2015 and i am facing problem in VS 2017

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38488503/unable-to-start-process-dotnet-exe

Comment: Please provide more information. What architecture are you aiming (x64, x86)? Are both installed? Do you run it with kestrel only or with IIS Express?  Is SSL enabled or not, if yes, does it run without SSL?

Comment: I am running it in visual studio   its architecture is  x64