# windows authentication in aspnet core app while debugging

Tags: debugging, asp.net-core, windows-authentication

I am trying to develop an application that uses AD for determining user access. I have implemented the windows authentication and it works when I deploy the app to IIS, but I want to use it while development time for debugging purposes. I have already configured the launchsettings.json file to have below.

```
"iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": true,
    "anonymousAuthentication": false,
    "iisExpress": {
        "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5001",
        "sslPort": 5002
    }
}
```

Why am I not able to get this working. Is there something else that I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

You said IIS-Express - do you have Web.config ?

```
<system.webServer>
    […]
    <security>
      <authentication>
        <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false"/>
        <windowsAuthentication enabled="true"/>
      </authentication>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: Yes, I do have a web.config file with the same settings and I made sure it is copied to the build folder.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the project and in the debug settings, changed the `launch options` to `IIS`. After that I got an error saying `dotnet.exe not found`. That error lead me to [Unable to start process dotnet.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38488503/unable-to-start-process-dotnet-exe), which says in IIS, `web.config` files are useless for aspnetcore projects. I then deleted the `web.config` file and it worked. I was able to get the user details into the `IHttpContextAccessor`.